# Transferring from one event to another

Tags: civievent

civiCRM: 5.37.0, using civiEvent
Drupal: 7.80

This is our first year using civiCRM, so rather than allowing participants to self-transfer from one event to another, I decided to do this myself. When I go to the transferring participant at "Manage Events" and click on "Transfer or Cancel" button (on the right, under "More"), I have the option of "Transfer or Cancel." Cancel works as it ought but Transfer gets "Select Contact" (and does nothing) rather than "Select Event" or some such tag.

My only option seems to be to cancel and manually register.

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Tom

Answer (score 1):

The function of Transfer is to move the registration from one participant to another. Its not to transfer the booking to another event. For that you'd need to cancel the participation record for this event and register the contact onto the new event. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If the events and the participation parameters correspond (paid/free etc.), you could alter the db-table civicrm_participant and change the event_id to the new/desired one. BUT please be careful, this is only a workaround in order to save time when you have to change a lot of records.